# Reuse existing environment variables in Docker Compose .env file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am involved in a Docker Compose project and we take advantage of the `.env` file possibility. However, I discovered that I can not reuse one environment variable while constructing another one, or reuse existing OS-level environment variables.

For example, this doesn't work:

```
VIRTUAL_HOST=domain.com
LETSENCRYPT_HOST=${VIRTUAL_HOST}
LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=contact@${VIRTUAL_HOST}
```

Any ways around it?

Comment: Docker not support nesting variables in .env file

Comment: After trying this approach several times I came to the conclusion that it is overkill. I can concatenate variables directly in docker-compose.yml and that works perfect. Not only, but having the kind of .env file you are trying to build proved to be really difficult to debug. My advice would be to not do that to yourself :) But I would be happy if somebody comes up with a better idea

Answer (score 0):

Create a entry script similar to this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

# Run a substitution because docker don't support nesting variables
export LETSENCRYPT_HOST=$(echo ${LETSENCRYPT_HOST} | envsubst)
export LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=$(echo ${LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL} | envsubst)

exec "$@"
```